# Is Apex Callout chaining from Javascript controller using Async/await or Promise possible?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, callout

I need to make 5 callouts serially. I have written 5 different apex classes. I want to chain these callouts from JavaScript controller using Async/Await or Promises. Had anyone worked on such scenario? Any problems or blockers? Each call is taking few seconds - so no timeout issue. I am logging each callout results, so I might get uncommitted work pending exception. Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no concern there. As long as each callout occurs before the DML in each Apex transaction, you'll be fine. For example, you can write your logic like this:

```
let result1 = await apexMethod1();
let result2 = await apexMethod2();
let result3 = await apexMethod3();
let result4 = await apexMethod4();
let result5 = await apexMethod5();
```

Each result will have been obtained from a *separate* transaction that each had their own *separate* governor limits.